# how to hide keyboard while closing layer which contains my TextField

Tags: cocos2d-x, textfield, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using TextField in my new project which is in cocos2d-x 3.2.It's working fine when i enter text and then enter then it hides my keyboard but when I enter text & i kept my keyboard opened at that time if i close my PopUp layer containing my text Field then my keyboard remained opened .  I don't know how i can hide or close my keyboard in this situation. please help...

Here is my Code ..

// Adding TextField in my Layer

```
TextFiledd = TextField::create("", "fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Cond_0.ttf" , ButtonFontSize);
TextFiledd->setContentSize(Size(Playername_bg->getContentSize().width ,Playername_bg->getContentSize().height));
TextFiledd->setPosition(Point(Playername_bg->getPositionX(),Playername_bg->getPositionY()));
TextFiledd->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ANCHOR_MIDDLE);
TextFiledd->setMaxLength(10);
TextFiledd->setMaxLengthEnabled(true);
TextFiledd->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(PlayerName::textFieldEvent, this));
TextFiledd->setColor(Color3B::YELLOW);

TextFiledd->setBright(true);

TextFiledd->setTouchAreaEnabled(true);
TextFiledd->setTouchSize(Playername_bg->getContentSize());

bgFrameSprite->addChild(TextFiledd,PopUpTag);
```

// Delegate methods

```
 void PlayerName::textFieldEvent(cocos2d::Ref *pSender, TextField::EventType type)
 {
playerNameText = (TextField*)pSender;
CCLOG(" Player name : %s",playerNameText->getStringValue().c_str());
std::string key = Player_Name;
PlayerSettings::setPlayerName(key.c_str(), playerNameText->getStringValue().c_str());

switch (type)
{
    case TextField::EventType::ATTACH_WITH_IME:
    {
        TextField* textField = dynamic_cast<TextField*>(pSender);
        Size widgetSize = WinSize;
        runAction(CCMoveTo::create(0.225f,Vec2(0, widgetSize.height / 12.0f)));
        textField->setTextHorizontalAlignment(TextHAlignment::LEFT);
        textField->setTextVerticalAlignment(TextVAlignment::TOP);     
        playerNameText->setText(str);
    }
        break;

    case TextField::EventType::DETACH_WITH_IME:
    {
        TextField* textField = dynamic_cast<TextField*>(pSender);
        Size widgetSize = WinSize;
        runAction(CCMoveTo::create(0.175f, Vec2(0, 0)));
        textField->setTextHorizontalAlignment(TextHAlignment::LEFT);
        textField->setTextVerticalAlignment(TextVAlignment: 
    }
        break;

    case TextField::EventType::INSERT_TEXT:
        break;

    case TextField::EventType::DELETE_BACKWARD:
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: my keyboard remained opened like this : http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/3141/110521140718_64ac4a858885861d7fce67eeb3c7056c.jpg even i replace my scene

Comment: In IOS platform, if you click the screen, the keyboard will disappear automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (cocos2d-x-3.11.1):

`textField->detachWithIME()`

on iOS and Android.

Comment: Outdated answer - the API no longer exists in newer versions of Cocos2DX.